# Show Vim command options

Tags: vim

This was a feature I used to have when I was first learning vim, and sometime between me customizing my `.vimrc` file, I must have disabled it some how.

Lets say I have this command I can enter

```
:TmuxNavigate
```

Now this command could take Left, Right, Up, or Down as options. Early on in my learning of Vim, I had a small line above the command line that would show any available commands that start with `:TmuxNavigate`

I've tried enabling `set showcmd`or `laststatus=2` but wasn't able to enable this feature.

Is this a feature I can enable or have I just completely lost my mind and imagined this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any good plugin should have documentation. Try `:h :TmuxNavigate` maybe

Comment: was more of an example really. This feature would work for any commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set wildmenu
```

Every command set up to complete arguments will do what you expect.

See `:help 'wildmenu'` and `:help 'wildmode'`.

Comment: You sir are a hero! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[space] [Ctrl+d] after command like:

```
:colorscheme [space] [Ctrl+d]
```